# Sharing Documents through program or some automation to do that?

Tags: document, folder, share

I have a document library with 200 folders and 200 Documents in the library  (one file in each folder).

I would like to share each folder with an individual in my company, so that other can not see the one individuals record / folder in any way.

I know that i can do that manually using the share option on each folder in the library but, I am looking for some automation way to do that.

I have full control over the site, but i am not an central administrator. but, I can share the files/folders manually.

can some one suggest me with the above permissions can i automate the document sharing in SharePoint ? and also, please provide me the code as well if you have.

Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add People/Group Column to your library
2. While adding documents or folder add person who needs to access that particular folder/document
3. Write a workflow on Document library to impersonate permission of every item using people/group column

This may help you to automate the document sharing.

Also you can use Power shell script instead of workflow.

Comment: Hi I am relatively new to the SharePoint workflows ,could you please suggest me some link on how to work with Library item level permissions through workflows? Or if you have some code that do please do suggest me.

Comment: To get Basics of Workflow go through this link: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflows-I-Basics-you-should-know-605304b0-08e8-43ea-b7dd-301d9c206f27

For changing permissions using workflow: http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html